# Conditionally uploading Excel SpreadSheet using FileUpload

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

Below Is my Vb Code which is getting the row count of the excel file. However, i want to throw an exception and give an error message if the row count is greater than 10k rows. How would i be able to do that? I have done my research on getting the row count but not sure how to throw an exception. The following is an ASP.Net Windows Form Application.

```
Dim xls As New Excel.Application
            Dim sheet As Excel.Worksheet
            Dim filePath As String = Path.Combine(GlobalVariable.savedPath, GlobalVariable.excelFileName)
            xls.Workbooks.Open(filePath)
            sheet = xls.ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(1)
            Dim maxSize As Integer = 2
            Dim row As Integer = 1
            Do Until sheet.Cells(row, 1).value Is Nothing
                row += 1
            Loop
            MsgBox("last Row is " & row - 1)
            xls.Workbooks.Close()
            xls.Quit()
            releaseObject(sheet)
            releaseObject(xls)
```

Comment: @slugster thank you for the edit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are already counting the rows, so you can modify your loop to continue only while row is less then 10,000.

```
        Dim row As Integer = 1
        Do 
            row += 1
        Loop while sheet.Cells(row, 1).value IsNot Nothing AndAlso row <= 10000
```

This will loop, incrementing row until there are no more rows, or if you hit 10,000. You can then check if row is 10,000 to decide if you want to show an error message.

```
   If row >= 10000 then
       MsgBox("Over 10000 rows")
       'If you want to throw an actual exception you can do:
       Throw new Exception("Over 10000 rows")
   Else
       MsgBox("last Row is " & row - 1)
   End If
```

## Updated to reflect OP Question Updates:

I don't know if I would recommend throwing an exception to handle if row reaches 10,000. Instead I would do like so:

```
    Private Sub BtnUpload_OnClick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles BtnUplaod.Click

        REM Save SpreadSheet
        Dim filePath As String = Path.Combine(GlobalVariable.savedPath, GlobalVariable.excelFileName)
        myfileUploader.saveAs(filePath)


        REM Open SpreadSheet
        Dim xls As New Excel.Application
        Dim sheet As Excel.Worksheet
        xls.Workbooks.Open(filePath)
        sheet = xls.ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(1)
        Dim maxSize As Integer = 2

        REM Loop through spreadsheet and count rows
        Dim row As Integer = 1
        Do
            row += 1

        Loop While sheet.Cells(row, 1).value IsNot Nothing AndAlso row <= 10000 'Exit loop when end of SpreadSheet is reached or if rows exceeds 10,000

        REM Release Resources
        xls.Workbooks.Close()
        xls.Quit()
        releaseObject(sheet)
        releaseObject(xls)

        REM Decide whether to accept upload, or reject and show error
        If row >= 10000 Then 'If row > 10000 delete file and show error

            REM Delete the file
            File.Delete(filePath)
            REM Show some sort of error to user - Its up to you how you want to do so. That is a seperate question
            MsgBox("Your Error")

            REM Else SpreadSheet is valid
        Else
            'Your Code code doing what you want with spreadsheet goes here
            MsgBox("last Row is " & row - 1)
        End If

    End Sub
```

This code will run when the users clicks a button called BtnUpload on the WebPage. You can put it anywhere you like though.

I think this is what you want. Is that correct?

Comment: how would i be able to handle this exception in order for the user to click okay and try again?

Comment: getting an exception of type 'system.exception' occurred in ---- but was not handled in user code.

Comment: Throw new exception("my Exception message") just throws a new exception with the message entered...You then have to handle it properly to do what you want. To answer how to allow the user retry, I would need to know more info about your program. Is it Asp.Net or windows Forms? If its ASP, is it WinForms, MVC, or AngularJS? Please update your question to provide more info in your question.

Comment: i updated the question above. Thank you. What i want to do is if it has more than 10k rows the upload fails and the user has to upload the file again. if it has 10k or less rows then the file upload occurs successfully

Comment: i am unable to use File.Delete(filePath) because it is saying this error.
`An exception of type 'System.IO.IOException' occurred in mscorlib.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: The process cannot access the file 'C:\ExcelFiles\InformationBook.xlsx' because it is being used by another process.`

Comment: My bad. You have to release the resources before trying to delete the file. I updated the answer.

Comment: My Friend. @mike100111 you rock!! Please upvote this question as it is a basic newbie programmer issue. I marked your answer as the correct answer. I see what i was doing wrong i was closing the file after the error message. Thanks again. if you see my name with questions being posted please continue to help.

Comment: My Pleasure...Happy programming